# Need total content in Aragog's Lair, set 75950

Tags: sets

Looking for info about Aragogs Lair, set #75950. I'm looking for the list of total parts for this set. I have 3 unopened bags with no numbers on them but they go to this playset - that's all I been able to find out. I was hoping to find out of all the total bags in the set and all contents in the box.

Comment: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75950-1

Comment: Hi Robert and welcome to Bricks.SE! I've taken the liberty to edit your question to be more readable - feel free to correct anything contrary to your intention. You're also welcome to browse the [help] or take the [tour] to learn more about this site, the community that's running it and the rules or customs of contributing here. Play well!

Comment: @IvanSanchez That comment should be an answer, since this is exactly what Robert is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75950-1) and [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/sets/75950-1/aragogs-lair/?spot=search_global#parts) have lists of parts included within this set. I am not sure how you have identified which set your elements belong to, but based on this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/zbvAicZXwxA?t=51) (at 00:51) three bags are all this set has inside.